# Redirect URLS for non-translated pages

Tags: i18n-l10n

Using Drupal 8 and the Language module.

The vast majority of the site is in the default language (en). We've added languages en-sci and en-sci-simp. Only a handful of pages, limited to a single content-type, are en-sci or en-sci-simp. As soon as a user goes to a page prefixed with /en-sci or /en-sci-simp, the language setting is prefixed on all other URLs.

This works as far as getting the user to the proper page, but instead of generating a menu link to ie /research, it is built as /en-sci/node/1000. This breaks a few things other than my sensibilities such as block visibility based on current path.

Is it possible to configure path generation to include the language prefix only for multi-language pages or content-types, leaving everything else "native"?